# Xcode 9 Source Control Navigator does not display all commits

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

If I compare the output of `git log` and the commit history in the Xcode 9 Source Control Navigator, there is a marked difference and many recent commits tend to be missing. For instance, right now `git log` lists 10 commits from today, whereas only 5 are visible in Xcode. I think Xcode's commit history does update occasionaly, but I haven't noticed any patterns in its behavior. In any case, I do not recall this being a problem up until Xcode 9 and the changes it includes to how source control is handled.

I've tried switching to another branch and then back to master. The *Pull* and *Fetch and Refresh Status* items in the *Source Control* menu have no effect. In *Preferences/Source Control*, *Refresh Local Status Automatically* is enabled. Restarting Xcode also does not help.

Admittedly, I do tend to do most of my interaction with git (pull, commit, push etc.) from a separate terminal window. Xcode is of course much easier to use for diffing.

Here are two screenshots that illustrate the issue (5 vs 15 commits):

[image: xcode git log output]
[image: abbreviated git log output]

This image shows the output of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`.

[image: git log graph output]

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you show the output of `git log --oneline` and the screen shot of the xcode source control Navigator which you mean somie commits missing?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT screenshots added.

Comment: Can you also provide the output by `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT graph screenshot added.

Answer (score 4):

Commits are not missing to show in xcode.

The different results caused by xcode only show the commits on `master` branch, while `git log` show the commits for all branches.

You can obviously find in the output of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` that the commits `ce514`, `12b6a`, `ef7a0`, `ccdfc` etc on `master` branch, while the commits from `8487c` to `f5da3` on other branches (not `master` branch).

And if you execute the command `git log master --oneline`, it will list the commits only on `master` branch, and the result will be same as xcode shows.

Comment: Hm, that is strange. If I do a `git log master --after="2018-01-16 00:00" --before="2018-01-16 23:59" --oneline`, I get the exact same list as when I do not specify `master`.

Comment: For Xcode, you can select the commits by committed date, such as All, Last 24 Hours, last 7 Days etc (https://imgur.com/a/maF3e). It you select Last 24 Hours, the output should be same as `git log master --after="2018-01-16 00:00" --before="2018-01-16 23:59" --oneline` (which you execute yestday). And if you select all, the commits listed on xcode should be same as `git log master --oneline`.